# Change mark order via parameter

Tags: vega-lite

I'm playing with vega-lite v5 and the new parameters and wanted to change the order of marks using an input element:

[image: Bar Chart with input for sort criteria]

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABEyTrDsU5kMB3OjEMwaZGMOc7ZZQ3IdtSZpLLKhhBwgnBQ7p7eUMJQANaUhgAUAJKyEDg06nBBTACehgAqSExhSAwA5BCGNLKYcOpIEbrBmHlhlACUiipImCiooMRIggxqaADaoAMg+j1MaABMABwAvgrTaCAAQvNoYmLrm+gAwnuoACwAzEcgMwAi5wCcAIy3MwCi58tvG3dbADFzmIbn8ZgBxc4vJ7vLYACW+AHZYegUsDFqsALrrEA4UxIBAQSagWQEuBbRzOVxYHohMIRNCgNo4cnoHBsWqYHpyLYINgMEK+BogVa3UkIVkgOnhLlKaUMtkcuoiv7iyUydSykDDUaS-gAD3mtWUjJAtRwDC56HlWrY2l0RNQExAhqUBp6eR6-E9ClkDEEgmxWKUyHUcVNzMlJnUPQAZjQA1sAMQXE6I5b6Za0zDqNhxKOCJrhpRQBjqDVbdmc4U4uCyKBsZS1Mimw2DEDx0Im9AoJSRrZsdRN0mCFUgT3tzuCbsgBZ9vIsrYARwYAR0-R0pDH8YDAHk8VA6BPQA3AnRdKa8Y0EFsbT0dWM0L9tSNH6gAAyUUFSnN5uAAdRoZR6FNU8mx0HknVAK8CVvUIZR6RBtAnWMRhCJQH1ZDE-hgm90EpFwnBpJQkLaNBUMEdCX11J9g2ot931FEs5HjFt22gEZWVAExAgABSQZRhzINJZGFD9KAxUUgA)

Is that possible?

I looked into the examples in the documentation but neither on `x`'s order property or with an `order` encoding I was able to use the param.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do this by sorting the data with a `window` transform. Although undocumented as of VL 5.1.0, window properties can be parameterised with `signal` values (and should take `expr` values with the next update). Here's a working example that separates your input element into the field to sort by and the direction to sort.

[Open below example in Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoDSACCikEzQAmABwBfBSbQgAQpeuoxYpy-QAwp5oACwAzH4gpgAiwagAnACMkaYAonF2yc5RrgBicWIR2aYA4nGJ8SmuABIZAOxV6ACSBTYOALpOIDhIAE5ICAaoxiCyA3CuMr2YATBsNFATStq6E+gAHp40sspooNs4DJiTcIJwUMdKbDiY7LJDhiCbSgCelvzPIPxvnZFjCGsQFNMG43ko4OscL1JmxprN5osALzIgDk6xRAB8MQACYHwhZwZGIlEfFHYgD82JRSBRqBRTBRID+4xh0wA8r1lHBoeDIdD0Hi5gSiWjMTjBQjCaiXmTKdToHAdtsyLSUVyFUrZCqme0lJh+vcAGawhBGUDAs0gQ00U67TRAmhkMaCVkgt5dWFc-nmx3O10cr1MjpKADu22UbBDluurgNAGtLEghkDYZg4LsOsGQMhegn0Ew+pZFVA2MplXsnhXrbbXCglBb7dXBHaU9N00HXlWbc3XNY9S8cICAI4MJCyW7qW6kIMOIA)

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 28},
      {"a": "B", "b": 55},
      {"a": "C", "b": 43},
      {"a": "D", "b": 91},
      {"a": "E", "b": 81},
      {"a": "F", "b": 53},
      {"a": "G", "b": 19},
      {"a": "H", "b": 87},
      {"a": "I", "b": 52}
    ]
  },
  "params": [
    {"name": "sortChoice", "value":"x",
     "bind": {"input": "select", "options": ["x", "y","-x","-y"]}},
    {"name": "sortBy",
     "expr":"sortChoice==='x'|| sortChoice==='-x' ? 'a':'b'"},
    {"name": "sortOrder",
     "expr":"sortChoice==='x'|| sortChoice==='y' ? 'ascending':'descending'"}
  ],
  "transform": [
    {
      "sort": [
        {"field": {"signal": "sortBy"}, "order": {"signal": "sortOrder"}}
      ],
      "window": [{"op": "rank", "as": "sorted"}]
    }
  ],
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "a", "sort": {"field": "sorted"}},
    "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

The parameter expressions could also be written as

```json
{"name": "sortBy", "expr":"test(/x/, sortChoice) ? 'a':'b'"},
{"name": "sortOrder", "expr":"test(/-/, sortChoice) ? 'descending' : 'ascending'"}
```